# PE формат: Способы импорта

Tags: windows, pe

PE формат предусматривает три способа импорта:

1. Импорт через таблицу импортируемых функций
2. Привязанный импорт (*Bound Import*)
3. Отложенный импорт (*Delay Import*)

Однако, изучая PE заголовок, я не обнаружил полей ответственных за указание используемого механизма импорта. Откуда загрузчик знает какой импорт следует использовать?

Comment: А в заголовке PE ничего этого и нет. Хоть что-то про импорты начинается с директорий, одна из которых и ссылается на нужные данные. Так что рекомендую посмотреть описание этих структур.

Comment: Хотя да. Таблица директорий содержит записи Import Table, Bound Table, Delay Import Descriptor.